# if / else in jquery animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use an `if` statement in jQuery to animate a `div` and all that's inside of it. I'm using code that's worked in other instances. For some reason the `else` statement has no effect, is it something about using it with animation?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container ').on('click', enlarge);
    function enlarge() {
        if ($(this).css('font-size') != '100%') 
            $(this).animate({ 'font-size': '100%' }, 1000); 
        else
            $(this).animate({ 'font-size': '62.5%' }, 1000); 
    };
});
```

The `if` works fine. The container loads on the page at `62.5%`, and clicking on it enlarges it to `100%`. Now I want to shrink it if someone clicks a second time, thus the `else`. But nothing happens on the second click.

If I take out the word `else`, then on click it enlarges to 100%, then shrinks back down again to 62.5%, which makes sense. But so the shrinking code works.

I also tried including the following in place of `else`, but same result, nothing.

```
else if
    ($(this).css('font-size') == '100%')
```

Comment: Did you check what is returned by `$( this ).css( 'font-size')`

Comment: `this` is not what you assume here. Apart from that is it usually better in terms or transparency, readability and maintainability to use a specific class for such things. Maybe something like `enlarged-text`. This also allows to keep the real styling rules in css, not in the logical code.

Comment: The font size is returned in px, not percentage Check http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1kg4g8zy/ You've to update your `if` condition

Comment: Also, I don't like the carriage return after the if. JavaScript has a tendency to treat carriage returns as statement separators in many circumstances!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css('font-size')
```

above code returns 'px' value.

if you want to get percentage value use this

```
$('.container')[0].style.fontSize
```